# PHP: Run class method in separate thread

Tags: php, multithreading

Is it possible to run a method of a class in a separate thread in PHP?
for example:
  Thread:

```
class AsyncThread extends \Thread {

    private $method;
    private $obj;
    private $params;
    private $timeout;

    public function __construct($obj, $method, $params, $timeout){
        $this->obj    = $obj;
        $this->method = $method;
        $this->params = $params;
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
    }

    public function run() {
        sleep($this->timeout);
        if (call_user_func_array([$this->obj, $this->method], $this->params)) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

Class:

```
class MyClass {

    private $param = 'username';

    public function callThread() {
        $thread = new AsyncThread($this, 'threadMethod', ['hello'], 5);
    }

    public function threadMethod($param) {
        echo "{$param} {$this->param}";
    }

}
```

When I try to call a method callThread, error:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->callThread();

Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
```

Or what else there are ways to start a thread, so that the flow had access to the methods of the object class MyClass?

Comment: I do not think that this is a duplicate. I asked a question about how to run a method of  class in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php), from PHP DOC:

> pthreads is an Object Orientated API that allows user-land
>   multi-threading in PHP. It includes all the tools you need to create
>   multi-threaded applications targeted at the Web or the Console. PHP
>   applications can create, read, write, execute and synchronize with
>   Threads, Workers and Threaded objects.
>
> A Threaded Object: A Threaded Object forms the basis of the
>   functionality that allows pthreads to operate. It exposes
>   synchronization methods and some useful interfaces for the programmer.

And here it is on [GitHub - PHTREADS](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads)

Comment: Thanks. I read about pthreads, but I have not found the answer to my question. It would be nice if you gave an example right here?